# assigning a priority to processes before they are launched

Tags: c#

I have a specific number of process(C# .exe)  that should be launched. how do i launch them according to their priority.

I know the Process.PriorityClass thing but it's not really useful because it only assigns the priority after the process is launched.

I have this code here (doesn't compares priority yet) but it doesn't work because the processes are not run so I can't assign the priority to them:

```
Process process1 = new Process();    
Process process2 = new Process();
Process process3 = new Process();

process1.StartInfo.FileName = "proc1";

process2.StartInfo.FileName = "proc2"'

process3.StartInfo.FileName = "proc3";

process1.PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.AboveNormal;

process2.PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.BelowNormal;

process3.PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.High;

process2.Start();

process2.WaitForExit();

process1.Start();

process1.WaitForExit();

process3.Start();
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What *doesn't run*?

Comment: it says that the priority class has no object. but if i set the priority after starting the process, it works. but then I wouldnt be able to launch them by priority

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a Dictionary with processes filenames and then use Linq query to sort them by ProcessPriorityClass with OrderBy. Then you just execute them iterating the list and assigning the right priority with is the value.

```
public void StartProcessesByPriority(Dictionary<String, ProcessPriorityClass> values)
{
    List<KeyValuePair<String, ProcessPriorityClass>> valuesList = values.ToList();

    valuesList.Sort
    (
        delegate(KeyValuePair<String, ProcessPriorityClass> left, KeyValuePair<String, ProcessPriorityClass> right)
        {
            return left.Value.CompareTo(right.Value);
        }
    );

    foreach (KeyValuePair<String, ProcessPriorityClass> pair in valuesList)
    {
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = pair.Key;
        process.Start();

        process.PriorityClass = pair.Value;

        process.WaitForExit();
    }
}
```

Comment: how do i initialize the list?

Comment: Manually, exactly like your code was doing. For example mydictionary.Add("proc1", ProcessPriorityClass.AboveNormal) and so on, and then, when needed, you call that method.

Comment: The most important thing is... priority can only be assigned to running processes. You can't assign it BEFORE.

Comment: alright, ill try that now, thx alot.
im dying here!! this project has no logic at all